# Keras: can I use a Flatten layer as input to multilayer perceptron model

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, multi-layer

I am trying to use MLP to classify images in Keras. My codes are:

```
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

# Prepare data generators for train and test
SIZE = 32
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    validation_split=0.2)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'train',
    target_size=(SIZE, SIZE),
    class_mode='categorical',
    batch_size=32,
    subset='training')

val_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'train',
    target_size=(SIZE, SIZE),
    class_mode='categorical',
    batch_size=32,
    subset='validation')

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'test',
    target_size=(SIZE, SIZE),
    class_mode='categorical',
    batch_size=32)

model_mlp = Sequential()
model_mlp.add(Flatten(input_shape=(32,32, 3)))
model_mlp.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model_mlp.add(Dropout(0.5))
model_mlp.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model_mlp.add(Dropout(0.5))
model_mlp.add(Dense(68, activation='softmax'))

# Compile
model_mlp.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',  # other choices: adam or SGD
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

print(model_mlp.summary())

history = model_mlp.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=100,
    epochs=100,
    validation_data=val_generator,
    validation_steps=100)

# Showing
show(history, model_mlp)
```

Can I use `Flatten` layer as input to multilayer perceptron model to reshape 32*32*3 image into vector as above? Thanks

**Any problems with my codes? because the `accuracy` is less than 5%, which is too low.**

Comment: I don't see any problem with using `Flatten` as your first layer. You have 68 classes, so an accuracy of 5% is better than the random classifier. Perhaps you could improve your results by using convolutional layers.

Comment: Cannot see any problem either; but I am not sure if using such a layer solely for reshaping is good practice; normally you should reshape your data as part of your preprocessing, before feeding them to your network - see the Keras example for [MNIST with MLP](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_mlp.py).